# Restrict PHP files outside application folder in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I restrict PHP files from getting executed outside the application folder?

I am using CodeIgniter and I have heard it somewhere that this thing is possible in CodeIgniter.

Comment: I am need of solutions not negative rating. So, if you have solution then help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Add public folder, move `index.php` into it, inside `index.php` change application and system folder settings to `../application` and `../system` respectively. Point domain to public folder.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary, I have added request in htacess which will surpass each request from index file and will result in not found.