# css is not loading in codeigniter 3.1

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1.
I am trying to read base_url from config file .
However hardcode value is working fine for the same .
 my code to read base_url is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>' />
<script src='<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assests/css/styles.css'); ?>' />
```

My config is as follow :

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:63342/CI/";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base\_url() function not working in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449386/base-url-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

Comment: You have typo `assests/css/` should be `assets/css/` and make sure you have included url helper in your autoload.php: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` or manually in your controller: `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: this link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913983/codeigniter-3-missing-css-files/44161022#44161022

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `base_url()` you have to load `url` helper first.Load it in `application/config/autoload.php` like this..

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Make sure that your files must be in root under `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assests/css/styles.css'); ?>' />
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assets/css/styles.css'); ?>' />
```

Make sure assets in root directory out side of application folder

As you have missed spelt it.

Answer (score 0):

try this
set folder location this way under CI Folder

```
CI
 application
 system    
 assets
```

then css link will be

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>' />
<script src='<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo base_url('assets/css/styles.css'); ?>' />
```

make sure to load url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```